# Get access token for Graph API

Tags: excel, vba

It's my first attempt to call a Graph API (with VBA), but I still could not get one access token for this.
Although I have read the documentation, I do not know what flow I need to apply to get access token without forcing the user to log in. Is this possible on my OneDrive Personal Accounts?

Here is what I have tried

```
Sub Test_GetToken()

    Dim xml As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim url As String

    url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/namelles_test@outlook.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    url = url & "?client_id=eca0b14c-1154-4768-8e45-2cb5639b7e0d"
    url = url & "grant_type=client_credentials"
    url = url & "&client_secret=VksZ8FeDF5XiRfqTBsgs628"
    url = url & "&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"

    xml.Open "POST", url, False
    xml.setRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"


    xml.send ("")
    Debug.Print "status=" & xml.Status, "readyState=" & xml.readyState

    Debug.Print xml.responseText

    Set xml = Nothing

End Sub
```

I created an account just for testing (username: nameless_test@outlook.com, userpass: nameless1234). Therefore, the real credentials can be used.
Can someone show me the flow I need to apply and how exactly the request is built?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the string here:    url = url & "grant_type=client_credentials" start with an ampersand?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put the email incorrectly in your code.

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/namelles_test@outlook.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

Should be:

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/nameless_test@outlook.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

Also, based on your comment, it seems that you have to put the `grant_type` in the body of the request instead of a query parameter in the URL.

```
xml.send ("grant_type=client_credentials")
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I've fixed the address but still get the following error:{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: efa6f9f2-cfa4-443a-929c-06eefb7a0d00\r\nCorrelation ID: d09be614-0371-482c-8d58-084d5cf74126\r\nTimestamp: 2017-06-24 19:21:34Z","error_codes":[90014],"timestamp":"2017-06-24 19:21:34Z","trace_id":"efa6f9f2-cfa4-443a-929c-06eefb7a0d00","correlation_id":"d09be614-0371-482c-8d58-084d5cf74126"}